# How can I quickly extract values from key-value pair vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, extract, key-value

I am new in R and I have some problems.
I have key-value pair vector `kv_vect` which contains lots of pairs:

```
> length(kv_vect)
[1] 296538
> head(kv_vect, 5)
[[1]]
[1] 3209

[[2]]
[1] 234

[[3]]
[1] 755

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 46
```

How can I quickly extract values (without keys) from kv_vect?

I just try to do this:

```
listVal<-c()
for (val in kv_vect) {
  listVal<-c(listVal,val)
}
```

but it works too long.

Comment: Something like this? Example: Extract value 3209: `c(3209, 234, 755, 3, 46, 3209, 766) |> as.list() |> 
  purrr::keep(~.x == 3209)`.

Comment: `unlist(kv_vect, use.names = FALSE)`?

Comment: @alxdid5 in that case, simply `as.numeric(kv_vect)` or `as.integer(kv_vect)` if you don't need type promotion, might be a bit faster.